# Can't find Role Services in Windows 7

Tags: iis-7, fastcgi, php5, php53

I'm trying to install PHP on Windows 7 Home Premium using these instructions:

[Using FastCGI to Host PHP Applications on IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-7/)

and a 1/3 of the way down on the page I have to do this:

```
 Server Manager -> Roles -> Add Role Services
```

and just cannot find Roles or Role Services.  Any ideas?

PHP is giving me a 500 error and I'm wondering if it's because I haven't done this role services thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That article is expecting you to be using a server OS, e.g. Windows Server 2008. You're not, so the equivalent on a home OS is - Control Panel -> Program and Features -> Turn Windows features on and off (left sidebar).

EDIT: upon further reading of the article, it actually tells you that anyway :)  [Here's the link + anchor.](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-7/#Windows_Vista_SP1)

EDIT #2: You might also want to consider using the [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.iis.net/webpi) instead, which will install and configure PHP on IIS for you.

Comment: +1 Use the Web Platform installer, especially for PHP stuff, it's awesome ^^